# Classical strings piece in Maryna Viazovska - 4/6 Automorphic Forms and Optimization in Euclidean Space

Tags: identify-this-song, classical-music, soundtrack

In [Maryna Viazovska - 4/6 Automorphic Forms and Optimization in Euclidean Space](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=25rGZYXpE1Y), strings play classical music from 0:04-0:14. Can anyone please identify this piece?

Answer (score 3):

Using Musipedia, I was able to identify this as:

[Beethoven, Ludwig van: String quartet No. 14 C# Minor Op. 131, 7th movement, 1st theme](https://youtu.be/ym31mIwFfxE?t=33m15s)

It's a bit slower, but your clip can be heard clearly in this video.

Comment: @Kid_A123 Great!  Please mark this as the accepted answer, there should be an option to select the green "checkmark".